# How can I get a Javascript Canvas to return x and y mouse positions?

Tags: javascript, function, event-listener, mouse-position

My goal is get live updating input from x and y position of my mouse. The y position works great, but when I went to add in the x position, I can't get anything but 'NaN'.

Why isn't this working for the X position as well? Is this not how to pass an object through a function? Is multiple objects the problem?

Here is my code:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',
    function(evt){
        var mousePos = calculateMousePosY(evt);
        paddle1Y = mousePos.y;
        //HERE IS WHERE I WANT X POSITION AS WELL
        paddle1X = mousePos.x; //Why doesn't this work?
    });
function calculateMousePos(evt){
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var root = document.documentElement;
    var mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left - root.scrollleft;
    var mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.top - root.scrollTop;
    return{
        x:mouseX,
        y:mouseY        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `var mouseX = ... - root.scrollleft;` to `var mouseX = ... - root.scrollLeft;` Capitalize the 'l' in 'left'.

Also your function is called `calculateMousePos` not `calculateMousePosY`. Remove the "Y".

Comment: Thanks, the 'Y' was a mistype when i transferred to SO. The capital L was the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

There are two changes in your code to be made,

- your function call had a mismatch of spelling `var mousePos = calculateMousePosY(evt);`and `function calculateMousePos(evt){...}` there was an extra "Y".
- and it is `scrollLeft`,with a capital "L".

Please find the code below:[Hope it helps]

**HTML:**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

**Javascript:**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(evt){
       var mousePos = calculateMousePos(evt);
       var values = 'Mouse position:' + mousePos.x + ',' + mousePos.y;
       display(canvas, values);
    });
function calculateMousePos(evt){
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var root = document.documentElement;
    var mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left - root.scrollLeft;
    var mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.top - root.scrollTop;
    return{
        x:mouseX,
        y:mouseY        
    }
}
   
    
 function display(canvas, values) {
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.font = '18pt Calibri';
        context.fillStyle = 'black';
        context.fillText(values, 10, 25);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: That's embarrassing. I'm not new to coding and I swear I really tried. 2 hours.... Thanks for the catch, great lesson to emphasize 1 step at a time and I should have created another block to catch the 'l'-->'L'

Comment: @user3158443: Happy to help. Everyone has been in your place :-) so no problem, Please do accept the answer which suits you the most. Thank you.